# Get one return from Azure RetailPrice API throw the Azure usage API

Tags: c#, azure, postman, rest, billing

I am not very experienced with Azure Rest API, and I have a task which calculating daily Azure costs with the help of the Azure APIs, I am currently using the usage API to know how much of what I have used and I use the RetailPrice API to know how much does an Azure service cost. I set a query filter at RetailPrice with MeterdId, armRegion but this is not enough to get just one resource in the result because I still need Skuname and ProductName or (SkuId / ProductId) which I don't get from Usage API. Please do someone know how I manage to only get one result from RetailPrice API using the UsageAggragtes API. That would also be ok if the solution uses a third API

Comment: Just go to billing it has everything you need to know, graphs break downs drill down and downloadable spread sheets

Comment: you mean this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing